# Weird fragments behind color

Tags: corel-painter

At the moment I am trying out CorelPainter 2020, so I am not really familiar with the program yet.
I just recognized some weird things behind my color.
Its just one layer and it can't be removed with the erazer.
Has anyone an idea where these come from and more importantly how to remove them?

[image]

If some more infos are needed I can provide them, just not sure which might be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your question earlier, so there may be some information already lost. I assume you're referring to the blobby bit in the middle of the white strokes? And are you saying that there's only one layer in your image? Or is it only the part of the image with the white strokes where you get the blobby bits?